# Is it possible to use functions on a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have the following code :

```
int n =3;
int A[n] = {3,2,1}, B[n], C[n];

han(n, A, B, C);
//--------------
void han(int disk, int source[], int target[], int spare[])
{
  ...      
  target[target -> end()] = source -> back();
  source -> back() = 0; 
// error : request for member 'end' in '* target', which is of non-class type 'int'
  ...     
}
```

I know that inside `han` `int target[]` is a pointer. 
Is there a way to use `target.end()` and `source.back()` inside `han`?

Comment: No, there is not such thing, unlike in Java, ActionScript, etc. In order to know where the last element is, you should add an argument telling how large your array is. See section "Arrays as parameters" of [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/). You could also consider using [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) instead. You can use `myVect.back()` on a vector.

Comment: What's wrong with things like `target[disk-1]`?

Answer (score 1):

Straight answer no. Better off using vectors for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that inside `han` `int target[]` is a pointer. Is there a way to use `target.end()` and `source.back()` inside`han`?

No. Pointers do not have member functions, so you cannot do such thing. A pointer contains the address of an object in memory. Nothing more, nothing less. It is impossible to find an end of an integer array, using just a pointer to an element of the array. You need to know the size.